# On closing modal and opening again, selected checkboxes doesn't persist and deault one renders

Tags: reactjs, state

I want that selected checkboxes should be visible even after closing and again opening the modal. I think somewhere state is not persisting. Please help me I'm new to react.

I have implemented every functionality which I want in my custom dropdown. Only remaining thing is that after selecting checkboxes when I close my modal and again open it, selected checkboxes should be visible.

App.js - This is where button to open modal is.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MultiSelectDropdown from 
'./MultiSelectDropdown/multiSelectDropdown';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  isOpen: false,
  }
  this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
 }

  toggleModal = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }

  render() {
  return (
  <div className="App" id="app">
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <p>
        Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>
      <a
        className="App-link"
        href="https://reactjs.org"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        Learn React
    </a>
    </header>

    <div style={{ margin: '40px' }}>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => this.toggleModal()} className="btn btn-outline-dark" style={{ height: '85px', fontSize: 'xx-large', float: 'left' }}>Trigger Modal</button>
    </div>

    {this.state.isOpen &&
      <MultiSelectDropdown isOpen={this.state.isOpen} toggle={this.toggleModal} />
    }

  </div>
);
 }
 }

export default App;
```

multiSelectDropdown.js : This contains my Modal and my custom dropdown which is imported.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from "react-modal";    
import Dropdown from './dropdown';

const customStyles = {
content: {
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    right: 'auto',
    bottom: 'auto',
    marginRight: '-50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    height: '70%',
    width: '60%',
    background: 'bisque',
 }
};

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

class MultiSelectDropdown extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        groupValue: [{key: 'Any', value: '0'}],
    }
    this.fetchCheckedValues = this.fetchCheckedValues.bind(this);
 }

fetchCheckedValues = (groups) => {
    console.log('groups checked', groups);
    this.setState({groupValue: groups});
}

render() {
    debugger;
    const staticOptions = [{key: 'Any', value: '0'}, {key: 'CurrentGroup', value: '1'}];
    const checkboxOptions = [{key:'G&A', value: '1'}, {key: 'DirSls', value: '2'}, {key:'IndSls', value: '3'}, {key: 'Prcrmt', value: '4'},
{key: 'TechOp', value: '5'}, {key: 'ITCost', value: '6'}, {key: 'Price', value: '7'}, {key: 'Growth', value: '8'}]
    return (
        <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen} style={customStyles} contentLabel="Dropdown Modal">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-dark" onClick={this.props.toggle}>Close</button>
            <Dropdown 
            groupId="group"
            staticOptions={staticOptions}
            checkboxOptions= {checkboxOptions}
            default={this.state.groupValue}
            getCheckedValues={this.fetchCheckedValues}
            />
        </Modal>
    )
}
}
export default MultiSelectDropdown;
```

dropdown.js : This is my custom dropdown

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './multiSelectDropdown.css';

class Dropdown extends Component { 
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        openDropdown: false,
        checkedOptions: [],
    }
    this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);
    this.renderValues = this.renderValues.bind(this);
    this.selectOption = this.selectOption.bind(this);
    this.isChecked = this.isChecked.bind(this);
 }

toggleDropdown = () => {
    this.setState({ openDropdown: !this.state.openDropdown });
}

renderValues = (checkedValues) => {
    let checkedOptions = [];
    checkedValues.map(option => checkedOptions.push(option.key));
    return checkedOptions.toString()
}

selectOption = (event, option) => {
    let selectedOption = this.state.checkedOptions;
    let staticOptionKeys = this.props.staticOptions.map(option => option.key); //remove static option if checking checkboxes
    if (event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            for (let x in staticOptionKeys) {
                let staticIndex = selectedOption.findIndex(option => option.key === staticOptionKeys[x]);
                if (staticIndex !== -1) {
                    selectedOption = [];
                }
            }
            selectedOption.push(option);
            this.setState({ checkedOptions: selectedOption });
        }
        else {
            let optionIndex = selectedOption.findIndex(x => x.key == option.key);
            if (optionIndex !== -1) {
                selectedOption.splice(optionIndex, 1);
                this.setState({ checkedOptions: selectedOption });
            }
        }
    }
    if (event.target.nodeName === 'A') {
        selectedOption = [];
        selectedOption.push(option);
        this.setState({ checkedOptions: selectedOption });
    }
    this.props.getCheckedValues(selectedOption);
}

isChecked = (option) => {
    let checkedValues = this.state.checkedOptions;
    let index = checkedValues.findIndex(x => x.key === option.key);
    let checked = (index !== -1) ? true : false;
    return checked;
}

render() {
    debugger;
    let renderCheckedValues = this.renderValues(this.props.default);
    return (
        <div className="search-controls">
            <div className="dropdown wd130" style={{ margin: '60px' }}>
                <button className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle wd130 ht34" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style={{ borderColor: '#b0bcd0', color: '#566f99', fontSize: '16px', background: '#F6FAFE' }}
                    onClick={() => this.toggleDropdown()}>
                    {renderCheckedValues}
                    <span className="caret mgL70"></span>
                </button>

                <ul className="dropdown-menu wd170" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style={{ height: '250px', overflowY: 'scroll', display: this.state.openDropdown ? 'block' : 'none' }}>

                    {this.props.staticOptions && this.props.staticOptions.map((res, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <a onClick={(event) => {
                                    this.toggleDropdown();
                                    this.selectOption(event, res)
                                }
                                }>
                                    {res.key}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}

                    <li role="separator" className="v-line" style={{ border: '1px solid rgb(227, 232, 238)' }}></li>

                    {this.props.checkboxOptions && this.props.checkboxOptions.map((res, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li className="checkbox-menu" key={index}>
                                <a>
                                    <span className="rc-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" className="rc-checkbox-input" onChange={(event) => this.selectOption(event, res)}
                                            checked = {this.isChecked(res)} />
                                        <span className="rc-checkbox-inner"></span>
                                    </span>{res.key}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default Dropdown;
```

Functionality is working fine. Only thing left is selected checkboxes should persist even after closing and opening the modal. Please help me I'm new to react. Thanks in advance.